# Trying to put array as an key-value pair in objects. Not getting desired output?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created an insert function.

```
insert(obj4, ["whisky", "balentine"], ["pasta", "pesto"]);
```

obj4 is the item to which I intend to put those arrays pairs as key-value pairs. The first item in each array is going to be key with the second item as a value pair. I am trying to output my temp object and I am only getting [object object]. What should I do now? Is the code correct?

I have created this function: -

```
function insert(obj, ...pairs){

    //Holds the objects temporarily
    var tempObj = {}; 

    for(let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(arguments[i].length > 2){
            console.log("Too long")
            return;
        } else {
            tempObj[arguments[i][0]] = arguments[i][1];
        }
    }

    //Trying to log my temp object 
    console.log("Test " + tempObj);
}

insert(obj4, ["whisky", "balentine"], ["pasta", "pesto"]);
```

Comment: Hi, checkout Object.from entries, it might help you and it is a built it function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: FCOL did you just try to console/log the object *without* prepending it with "Test " +?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print object using string concatenation. So its printing [object object] using toString. Your code is correct though. Just print only object and you would be able to see actual Object

```js
function insert(obj, ...pairs){

    //Holds the objects temporarily
    var tempObj = {}; 

    for(let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(arguments[i].length > 2){
            console.log("Too long")
            return;
        } else {
            tempObj[arguments[i][0]] = arguments[i][1];
        }
    }

    //Trying to log my temp object 
    console.log(tempObj);
}

insert({}, ["whisky", "balentine"], ["pasta", "pesto"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add onto what vipul patel said, if you wanted to console out the string Test and the object you could do, `console.log('Test', tempObj);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also did this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
function insert(obj, ...pairs){
            if(pairs.length > 0){
                var result = pairs.reduce(function(accumalator, currentValue){
                    accumalator[currentValue[0]] = currentValue[1];
                    return accumalator;
                }, obj);
                return result;
            }else{
                return obj;
            }
        }
        
var obj4 = {"ice":"cream"};
var result = insert(obj4, ["whisky", "balentine"], ["pasta", "pesto"]);
console.log(result);
```